# smack SSL/TLS required by client but not supported by server

Tags: ssl, openfire, smack

I am trying to establish secure connection between Openfire and smack client and get the error

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$SecurityRequiredByClientException: 
SSL/TLS required by client but not supported by server
```

I am using `Openfire 4.0.1` and have enabled `5223`. Using `Smack` on client side and connection configuration is as follows:

```
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
configBuilder.setServiceName(service_name);
configBuilder.setHost(server);
configBuilder.setPort(5223);
setHttpsClient(); // Sets a SSL context
configBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(mSSLContext);
configBuilder.setSocketFactory(mSSLContext.getSocketFactory());
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection( configBuilder.build( ) );
connection.connect();
```

After initial exchange server sends

```
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism>
<mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism>
<mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression 
xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method>
</compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register 
xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
```

which does not contain `starttls`.

Comment: So? What do you want us to do about it? The message is perfectly clear. The server doesn't support TLS so neither can the client.

Comment: I have enabled SSL on server. The 5223 port is enabled for SSL. Also the properties for SSL are set as xmpp.socket.ssl.active true, xmpp.socket.ssl.keypass, xmpp.socket.ssl.keystore is set to resources/security/keystore. So I expect server to support TLS. Please tell me if there is any other setting required on server to enable TLS

Comment: STARTTLS is usually done on Port 5222.

Comment: ok... but why is the error 'SSL/TLS required by client but not supported by server' while connecting to 5223 when SSL is enabled. Also I observed that with the same server set-up if I use Spark client, it connects using SSL. I could see that Spark uses DummySSLSocketFactory and not the actual certificate. I want to set up SSL connection with certificate validation

Comment: I am using the self-signed certificates generated by openfire. I exported the RSA certificate and kept in android client's raw directory and using it to create the SSL context like this 
InputStream caInput = context.getResources( ).openRawResource ( R.raw.sscert );

Comment: I was trying to connect to 5222 but was getting above error immediately, but while connecting to 5223 there was some initial handshake and then an error was thrown. So I kept exploring the connection issue related to 5223. After a lot of research I found that smack needs TLS and that is supported only on 5222. In my code above i had to just remove the line  
configBuilder.setSocketFactory(mSSLContext.getSocketFactory());
and set port to 5222 and it worked like charm!!